# How to link to SharePoint documents from OneNote?

Tags: office, onenote

We have a company SharePoint server on which I store both documents and OneNote notebooks. I want to be able to put a link on a OneNote page which, when clicked, will open a document which is stored on SharePoint in the appropriate Office application (Word, Excel, PowerPoint etc).

Is this possible, and if so, how do I set up the link?

Comment: Have you set the library default (under advanced settings) to force the client application as the default instead of the web application?

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the link from the document like this:

[image]

2. Paste into your OneNote

Comment: is there a way to link a file so that is shows the contents of the SharePoint file ?

Comment: Insert ribbon tab > File Attachment > (browse for file) > Insert Printout

Answer (score 0):

If you export to excel any document library you will get a list of functioning absolute hyperlinks that you can copy paste into one note

Library ribbon - open in excel

Comment: The links work fine from Excel, but when I copy / paste into OneNote and then click them, they launch the URL in my default browser (Firefox). This then downloads a copy of the file which I can open, but it is obviously not the SharePoint version of the file.

Comment: What do you mean by the 'sharepoint version' of the file? that it is opened in office web applications? You did not mention this in your post. The file it is opened as a SAVE but for sure it is the exact same file that is on the platform.

Comment: As my original post said I want the file to open in the appropriate [Desktop] Office application. We do not use web applications on our server as they take up too much memory. I want to know if a link from OneNote can be made to open the file in Word, Excel etc as happens when the link is (as you have described) in Excel as exported from SharePoint.

Comment: This is the standard behaviour of the link (also in IE): the bar that asks you if you want to save or open. This page http://claytoncobb.com/2011/01/07/sharepoint-2010-how-to-open-files-that-prompt-for-save-or-cancel/   explains you eventually how to change this behaviour at a web application level. Not sure it is worth the stress.